# Spanned divisors and Base Points

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth algebraic variety.

We say that a line bundle $\xi\in H^1(X,\mathcal{O}^\ast)$ is *spanned* is for each $x\in X$ there is a global section $s\in H^0(X,\mathcal{O}(\xi))$ with $s(x)\neq 0$.

Let $\xi=[D]$ be the line bundle associated to a divisor $D$. If $\xi$ is spanned, why can we say that the linear system $|D|$ is base-point free?

Basically for each $x$ I want to find $D'\in|D|$ such that $x\notin D'$.

Comment: Given $x$, just choose a section $s$ such that $s(x) \neq 0$. Then take $D'$ to be the zero-set of the section $s$.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh: Great! why is $D'$ equivalent to $D$?

Comment: Well, the definition of the line bundle $O(D)$ associated to $D$ in terms of rational functions says that the global sections $H^0(X,O(D))$ are precisely the rational functions on $X$ with poles (at most) along $D$. If $s$ is such a rational function with poles along $D$, and zero-set $D'$, then $div(s)=D-D'$. This means that $D$ and $D'$ are linearly equivalent.

Comment: Dear @Asal: why not transform your comments into a regular answer? My fingers are itching to upvote you :-)

Comment: Dear @Georges, I was rushing because I wanted to go for a walk in the sunshine while I could. But now your itch can be scratched!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that the line bundle $\mathscr{O}(D)$ is spanned. So given $x \in X$, there exists a section $s \in H^0(X, \mathscr{O}(D))$ such that $s(x) \neq 0$. Let $D'$ denote the divisor of zeroes of the section $s$; then $x$ is not contained in $\mathrm{Supp}(D')$.

The remaining issue is to show that $D'$ is linearly equivalent to $D$. To do this, we need to show there's a rational function $f$ on $X$ such that $\mathrm{div} f = D'-D$. But there's a correspondence (explained in detail e.g. in Shafarevich Volume 2, VI.1.4) between global sections of the bundle $\mathscr{O}(D)$ and rational functions $f$ on $X$ such that $\mathrm{div} f + D \geq 0$; moreover, if $s \in H^0(X,\mathscr{O}(D))$ has zero-set $D'$, and $s$ corresponds to a rational function $f$, then $D'=\mathrm{div} f + D$.

So our chosen section $s$ from the first paragraph yields a rational function $f$ such that $D'-D=\mathrm{div} f$, which means the two divisors are linearly equivalent, as we wanted.

Comment: Itch scratched, thanks:-)